# Dendogram different colours by label name

Tags: r, dendextend

Hope you are all doing good.

I use a dendogram:

```
d <-
  dist(Correlation_Test)
hc <-
  hclust(d, "ave")

plot(hc)
```

It works fine and shows at the End the dendogram. Dendogram has different labels. Some of them with the prefix A some with B. I want now to colorize the labels and perhaps branches, based on the label, if its A or B.
I found dendextend package. But I didnt manage to automatically colorize the labels based on their prefix.

Can someone help me :)

Example data of Table which is used for Correlation

```
A Data 1     A Data 1    B Data 1 
0.1666667    0.5         0.6666667
0.6666667    0.6666667   0.6666667
0.5          0.5         0.6666667
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Do you need the same exact same dendogram function or another one is okay for you?

Comment: @YacineHajji Everything is ok!

Comment: @Quinten did it

Comment: @GregorO All right :) I added 2 examples that you can use with your `hc` object. You just have to play with number of clusters and colors. If the 'A' or 'B' labels don't depend on your cluster then my example doesn't work...

Comment: A and B don't depend on my clusters :( . They spread all around

Answer (score 1):

Please find an example with `fviz_dend` function from `factoextra` package.

#### Basic dendrogram

```
### Initiating data
data(USArrests)

### Initiating reproducing example: distances for dendrogram
dd <- dist(scale(USArrests), method = "euclidean")
hc <- hclust(dd, method="ave")

### Basic dendrogram
plot(hc)
```

[image]

#### Option where you color labels

```
### Option where you can either color branches or labels or both (latest option chosen)
# Libraries import
library(dendextend)
library(factoextra)

# Dendrogram with only branches and labels colored
fviz_dend(hc, k=3,
          cex=0.5,
          k_colors=c("#00ffae", "#00c1ff", "#f000ff"),
          color_labels_by_k=TRUE)
```

[image]

#### Upgraded option

```
# Dendrogram with both branches and labels and cluster colored
fviz_dend(hc, k=3,
          cex=0.5,
          k_colors=c("#00ffae", "#00c1ff", "#f000ff"),
          color_labels_by_k=TRUE,
          rect=TRUE,
          rect_border=c("#00ffae", "#00c1ff", "#f000ff"),
          rect_fill=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: What I like with upgraded option is that it tells you where you exactly cut your clusters (what inertia point)